# Getting wrong result when checking string contains in another string

Tags: c#

result should retrun T3 but it retursn T2

My code:

```
    var fileName = "Code25T3.csv"
    var code = GetCode(fileName);// this should return T3 but it returns T2

    public static bool ContainesIgnoreCase(this string input, string contains)
    {
        return input.IndexOf(contains, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }

    private static string GetCode(string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("D1"))
                return "D1";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("D2"))
                return "D2";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("D3"))
                return "D3";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("D4"))
                return "D4";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("T1"))
                return "T1";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("T2"))
                return "T2";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("T3"))
                return "T3";
            if (fileName.ContainesIgnoreCase("T4"))
                return "T4";

            return null;
        }
```

**Update**

Please check the following unit test :in the file name when changing from Code to Lot it fails.

```
        [Test]
        public void StringContain2Test()
        {
            var fileName1 = "Lot25T3.csv";
            Assert.True(fileName1.ContainesIgnoreCase("T3"));
            Assert.False(fileName1.ContainesIgnoreCase("T2"));

            var fileName2 = "Code25T3.csv";
            Assert.True(fileName2.ContainesIgnoreCase("T3"));
            Assert.False(fileName2.ContainesIgnoreCase("T2"));
        }
```

Comment: When running your code it returns T3 and not T2 as you said... that means that it works as you expected

Comment: Is there any other code you are not showing us? Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: @ChrisK when the file name changed from code to Lot then i have issue please see my update

Comment: ok i see that Lot25T3 contains also T2